# Extracting a list from inside a cell in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which a column has a list of values. For example

```
    created      values
0   2016-12-21   [1,2,3,4]
1   2016-12-28   [6,7,8,9]
2   2017-01-4   [13,12,11,10]
```

Say I want to extract the last value in the row column in a different `list(13,12,11,10)`. I have written some code using the `iloc[]` function which looks like below, but I am getting the error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
i=0
c=[]
while value in a['values']:
    i=i+1
    c=a['values'].iloc[i]    
c
```

Below is the stack trace

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a6f26f30f73d> in <module>()
      2 user_id=[]
      3 c=[]
----> 4 while user_id in a['user_ids']:
      5     i=i+1
      6     c=a['user_ids'].iloc[i]

C:\Users\aditya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in             __   contains__(self, key)
    844     def __contains__(self, key):
    845         """True if the key is in the info axis"""
--> 846         return key in self._info_axis
    847 
    848     @property

C:\Users\aditya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py in    _     _   contains__(self, key)
   1232 
   1233     def __contains__(self, key):
-> 1234         hash(key)
   1235         # work around some kind of odd cython bug
   1236         try:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Your question seems a bit off. It is very unclear where are you even picking user_ids from, since the example dataframe only has columns created and values. Could you please edit your question to include all the important ingredients?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The dersired output is just the list [13,12,11,10]

Comment: user_id was just something I was trying out, even without that line, I am getting the same error

Comment: Basically Im trying to iterate through the user_ids column to get the last list in the dataframe

Comment: oh sorry, the name of the column values is user_ids, ill just edit the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) with `-1` for select last value of column `values`:

```
print (a['values'].iloc[-1])
[13, 12, 11, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

you could just do

```
a['values'].iloc[-1]

[13, 12, 11, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
a.loc[len(a)-1][1]
```